# Identify a 90's Disney movie featuring spaceship "surprise" and futuristic Neo Nazis

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, disney

Can you help me identify this 90's movie about a space ship ambushing a superiorly numbered, and larger ships, piloted by futuristic Neo Nazis.  What is at stake?  A planet full of water.  It was a disney movie.

Comment: Michael can you give some more details about when you saw this movie? Did you see it in the theater or on TV? Cartoon or Live Action?

Comment: Here's a list of Disney movies, if it helps: http://www.disneymovieslist.com/disney-movies.asp

Comment: http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Spaceship_Surprise

Comment: A you sure this was a Disney release?
The only thing close is Treasure Planet:
http://www.disneymovieslist.com/movies/details.asp?mov=treasure-planet
And they most certainly battled space pirates, not Neo Nazis.

Comment: by any chance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager ? it didn't completely fit, but, well, almost...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/what-is-this-story-about-20-y-o-inexperienced-kids-fighting-against-a-stronge

Answer (score 9):

The Corvette *Surprise* is the dead giveaway. It's Titled [**In the Fold**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117729/), with an alternate title of [**Star Command**.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117729/)

It's NOT disney - it's a UPN release, done by "High Command Productions" for Universal Television, released 1996.

- The esteemed Nigel Bennett (noted for playing La Croix in Forever Knight) leads the bad guy cast.
- Morgan Fairchild and Chad Everett play the short lived officers in charge of the Surprise.

Some additional information:
[imdb](http://www.90lostminutes.com/2011/02/star-command.html)
[B-Movie Reviews](http://www.90lostminutes.com/2011/02/star-command.html) < excellent visuals

I strongly suspect this to be the movie in question.

Answer (score 2):

it was UPN's 4 hour moive/pilot Star Command Chad Evert and Morgand Fairchild were the short lived officers assigned to give the newly commissioned Navel academy ensigns there shake-down cruise.
  Caught between a newly colonized world and your space nazis (I think it was the draconia Combine) The Upshot was the combine has been claim jumpping collony worlds in order to force a political takeover of (Confederation?) however the Surprize catches the combine about to invade and kill all the colonists. The Combine they doesn't want it revealed, because it might start a full-scale shooting war.
  The Suprize's crew of rookies as the only ship in the area must stall the Combine long enough for the fleet to arrive; and apply unconvetonal tactics to survive while contending with their own internal issues.   i have or had it on tape somewhere.

Comment: While we appreciate your input, it looks like Aramis already provided this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild shot.  The first title to come to mind is "Ice Pirates".  Not a perfect match - 90's, not Disney - but it is set in space and water's a valuable commodity.  Anybody who's seen it, can confirm or refute?

Comment: I don't recall Neo Nazi's in Ice Pirates, the space herpes yes, but no Nazi's.  Still that was a long time ago...

Answer (score 1):

If it's supposed to be comedy/parody it could be [(T)Raumschiff Surprise - Periode 1](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0349047/). Not Disney, not 90s, but the name of the spaceship matches and one of the villains (Jens Maul) could be considered a 'space nazi'. Planet Earth is at stake (so, that IS a lot of water).