# Identify movie about cadets on a training mission

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie about a group of cadets on a training space craft. Their commander (played by Gary Lockwood I think) and a blond female weapons officer are killed early on. This left the cadets to find ways to stop the enemy. They are able with a number of clever maneuvers to reduce an invasion fleet of the enemy such that it is no longer a viable force for invasion.

Can Anyone Identify this movie from more than 10 years ago and maybe 40?

Comment: Can you elaborate the characteristic of enemy?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/what-is-this-story-about-20-y-o-inexperienced-kids-fighting-against-a-stronge

Answer (score 7):

[*Star Command*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117729/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1996) (Also known as *In the Fold*)

I remember it because it had Morgan Fairchild as an attractive officer… who gets killed almost at the beginning of the movie.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the movie is "[In the Fold](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117729/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)", also known as "Star Command".

Here is a link to its description:

> A crew of freshly graduated space navy cadets find themselves fighting
>   with opponents from breakaway Earth colonies after their commanding
>   officers are killed in an attack.

Comment: Thanks for posting! Can you add some details explaining how this matches the details given in the question? Details are helpful both for the original poster and any future visitors.

Comment: You may wish to note that the film you've identified is the same film (albeit marketed under a different name for legal reasons) as the one in the answer above.